# Fractions and decimals

Tags: fractions

Ten companies sponsored a tournament and decided to give M rupees collectively.Two companies dropped and remaing agreed on paying their share equally.What was the increase in share of each company? The answer is M/40.How this answer comes.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Before the two companies drop, assuming that the **ten companies** split M rupees equally, each company pays **M/10**. After two companies quit, the remaining **eight companies** would each pay **M/8**.

Comment: what is the increase in their share?

Comment: If each company used to pay M/10, but now pay M/8, what is the increase?

Comment: M/8-M/10 is the  increase in the share.